# Do air particles "fly"? If not, how do they stay afloat?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, gas, brownian-motion

I was reading my old physics textbook (from middle school), and it mentioned something about the idea of having non-existing attractive forces between particles like air. "We would live in a very dull world."

This made me wonder, what would've happened if there are no bonds between air particles, or what if air particles stop moving entirely one day?

Will all the air particles just sink to the ground? (pulled by gravity)

Hence, the question: how do air particles "stay afloat" in the first place?

Comment: What is a particle, in your mind? What is a "bond between particles"? It sounds like you're using "particle" as a covering term for both atoms *and* molecules..

Comment: Yes, that's a strange set of statements: air particles don't attract each other significantly?

Comment: Imagine a room of playpen balls where the floor is constantly shaking. The balls would bounce around off each other, still affected by gravity but never settling on the ground. The shaking floor adds sufficient kinetic energy to overcome gravity and attractive forces, same as the Sun's heat does. There would still be more balls closer to the floor due to the weight of the ones above— Pressure and density. If the floor stopped shaking/Sun stopped shining, then the balls/particles would quickly bleed away their kinetic energy/heat, and settle/freeze into a layer on the ground.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SRaDpDT_znY

Comment: Are you asking about the various molecules in the atmosphere, or the dust and pollen, etc., that float around, intermixed with the atmosphere?

Comment: Do air particles fly, as in move through the air?  Then yes! ;)

Comment: `how do air particles "stay afloat" in the first place` - The very rough answer is that they get knocked by the particles below them who get knocked by the particles below them who .... get knocked by particles bouncing off the ground. In reality it's a bit more complicated than that but that's the gist of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How come gas molecules don't settle down?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2032/); [Why don' molecules of gas settle?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/327186/247642)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I will list your questions and answer them one by one.

1. what if air particles stop moving entirely one day?

This scenario is what happens when the temperature is very low. For really no motion at all you would need absolute zero temperature. But well before you get to absolute zero you get to another case: the gas turns to liquid, and then, when colder still to solid (except for special cases such as helium). Forming a liquid usually involves the attractive forces between molecules, but even if there were no attractive forces, the gas would eventually form a type of liquid. It would then lie in a big pool on the ground (while we all die for lack of oxygen).

2. Will all the air particles just sink to the ground? (pulled by gravity)

yes, see previous ans.

3. Hence, the question: how do air particles "stay afloat" in the first place?

They stay afloat through collisions. All the particles are indeed falling down owing to gravity, but they also bump into one another. You might guess that after a while they would on average sink lower and lower, but what happens instead is that there are more particles, that is, a higher density, at the bottom than at the top. And the ones at the very bottom do not sink any lower because they bounce off the ground. If they stuck to the ground then the whole atmosphere would itself fall and fall until it was all stuck to the ground. But they bounce off, and thus they provide a layer of gas near the ground. This layer then supports the one above it, because of collisions: the particles arriving from above get bounced back up again. And that layer in turn supports the one above it. And so on.

So the whole atmosphere is dynamic: between collisions every particle has a downward acceleration. During collisions the two particles bounce off one another. There is a higher density lower down, which results in more upward-directed collisions for a downward-moving particle than an upward-moving one.

All this can be captured precisely in equations, but I guessed you preferred the picture in words.

3B. *But what if the molecules in the air did not collide with one another, only with the ground. Would the atmosphere fall down then?*

This is an added paragraph suggested to me by some helpful comments by nanoman. He points out that in the scenario where the molecules do not collide with one another, they would still fly up high into the atmosphere after bouncing off the ground, following huge parabolas around 10 kilometres high, and overall the density distribution would still be the same! In this case the atmosphere thins as you go up because there are fewer molecules with enough energy to get that high. The above discussion in terms of layers is appropriate for the actual atmosphere because on average the molecules only travel tiny distances (less than a micron) before colliding.

P.S. I would like to add that the word 'bounce' is not quite right for what happens when air molecules hit the ground. In fact they mostly arrive and stick for a very short time called the 'dwell time', and then they get kicked or shaken off and zoom off in a random direction. The energy of the molecules coming away from this process is on average equal to the thermal equilibrium energy with which they arrived. So after averaging over time the net effect is like bouncing.

Comment: Concerning questions #1 and #2, I recommend reading the classic sci-fi short story ["A Pail of Air"](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/51461) by Fritz Lieber.

Comment: I feel like maybe add the equations for the more curious readers?

Comment: The distribution of molecules in a gas is essentially the same even if they don't collide with each other. All you need is that when a molecule hits the ground (or other boundary), it bounces. Each molecule could follow a perfect parabola between such bounces. The average energy of a molecule in the atmosphere could launch it several kilometers up with no collisions.

Comment: If I understand correctly, is the reason the air molecules don't run out of energy because of external heat sources? Would the atmosphere be thinner (less high) if the sun gave less heat?

Comment: @IvoBeckers Yes. There is incoming heat from sun, and outgoing infrared radiation into space. The result is the observed temperature profile. If there was less from sun, the temperature would be lower, and then in equilibrium the atmosphere would be more dense and not as high.

Comment: @nanoman I like your comment on parabolic trajectories, though I suspect the resulting density distribution may then be different because the particles would spend more time on average at the top rather than the bottom of their flight path.

Comment: My guess is that in a sea of air slush around 0K there would not be enough time to notice the lack of oxygen ;-). Another detail is that "there is a higher density lower down, which results in more collisions" -- true; but the important thing is that because of the pressure gradient there are *more upward directed* collisions. That is what keeps the particles afloat, and it is true (relatively) independent of the particle's direction of movement.

Comment: I don't like your post-script. They do not "unstick and fly off", and it is extremely misleading to say "the same energy with which they arrive". Rather, they usually get kicked off, and *because the air near the ground is roughly at equilibrium* the energy that gets transferred to them in kicking them off is on average the same as the energy that they had on arrival.

Comment: @user21820 thanks; your comment states more fully precisely what is meant by the words "on average" in my post-script.

Comment: You're welcome, but why not just edit to fix it, then I can remove my comments? (Long comment threads on SE don't get read by a significant fraction of readers.) And to clarify why it is misleading, non-science people who read your postscript would think that it gets stuck but is still holding on to its energy upon arrival and hence when it gets unstuck it leaves with that same energy...

Comment: @user21820 done

Comment: Hmm, sorry but I still don't like the "unstick" for the reason I've explained. Until it is clarified to remove ambiguity for non-science readers (who would have no idea what "thermal equilibrium" means), I'll leave my comments.

Comment: @AndrewSteane No, it works out. Each molecule spends more time at the top of its trajectory, but *fewer molecules* have enough energy to reach higher altitudes. Free-fall conserves the energy $H = p^2/2m + mgz$ and the phase-space element $d^3\mathbf{r}\,d^3\mathbf{p}$, so it preserves the equilibrium distribution $f(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{p}) = e^{-H/kT}$. Another way to see it: This $f$ is a steady solution of the *collisionless* Boltzmann transport equation. So I think collisions should be deemphasized in your answer. They matter for atmosphere *dynamics* but not for the equilibrium profile.

Comment: @nanoman Oh yes what a lovely insight. If you wanted to add that as a further answer then I would direct readers to it.

Comment: @AndrewSteane Thanks, I could do that -- or if you agree with me, you could improve *your* answer by removing the stuff about "They stay afloat through collisions." The atmosphere would be just as high without collisions.

Comment: @nanoman well hang on: the mean free path is tiny. So they stay afloat through collisions. If there were no collisions then they would perform those huge parabolas which you mentioned.

Comment: @AndrewSteane I guess there is a difference of interpretation. You're looking at why *individual* air molecules stay afloat for long periods, while I'm looking at why the molecules *collectively* stay afloat (i.e., a substantial number are always present well above the ground). I thought the latter was responsive to OP, and it doesn't require collisions to explain.

Comment: @AndrewSteane My concern is your answer could give the impression that if we could "turn off" collisions, most of the atmosphere *would* collapse to the ground. The dynamics and detailed variations of the atmosphere would change significantly, but it would not collapse and would retain much the same gross average structure.

Comment: @nanoman yes I'll edit the ans a bit. Do add one if you like.

Answer (score 14):

They stay apart because they are moving. A typical speed for an air molecule in the atmosphere would be 450 metres per second (rather faster than the speed of sound). When they hit each other they bounce off each other.

How do we know that the molecules are moving? Suppose that we pump some air into a closed container. We can detect that the trapped air exerts a pressure on the inside of the container. This is just what would happen if fast-moving molecules were continually hitting it. But, you might say, there  could be other causes of the pressure. Better evidence of molecules' motion is needed. Such evidence would be *Brownian motion*, in this case the observed jiggling motion of particles (like pollen grains) large enough to see under a microscope, in air. [The molecules of the air are far too small to see under a microscope, but they jostle the larger particles that we *can* see.]

What makes the air molecules move like this? They do it naturally. Scientists have known for a long time that *temperature* is a measure of how fast gas molecules are moving, or to be more accurate, of the mean *kinetic energy* of the molecules. And this is sustained by energy radiated from the Sun. If the temperature dropped very, very low the molecules would almost stop moving and pile up on the ground. [Of course liquefaction would take place, but that's another story.]

Answer (score 6):

@Steeven's point about there not being enough space on the ground can also be described in terms of there not being enough energy states near the ground. To take another familiar example, when you fill a bathtub the water "stacks"; some molecules go on the bottom, so go above them and have slightly more GPE, and so on. (If you flesh out this idea further, with energy to be general rather than altitude, you get to [Fermi levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_level) for particles in a suitable electrostatic potential.)

The occupation probability at energy $E$ is proportional to $\exp(-\beta E)$, with $\beta$ the [thermodynamic beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_beta). The approximation $E\approx mgh$ for mass-$m$ particles makes this factor $\exp(-\beta mgh)$, so air thins exponentially with length scale $\frac{1}{\beta mg}=\frac{k_BT}{mg}$, which works out to a few kilometres. This is why air pressure is lower at the top of a mountain. Unsurprisingly, this makes carbon dioxide thin faster (i.e. with a shorter length scale) than argon, which thins faster than oxygen, which thins faster than nitrogen.

Comment: You've kind of added some entropy as an after thought to a model of quantum degenerate matter. When actually, entropy is the whole point, and the degenerate matter model is entirely wrong (per Michael Seifert's comment).

Comment: @ComptonScattering Indeed, I've been meaning to add the bathtub ends up shallower than the real atmosphere, and more similar to the model he refuted, because the non-gravitational forces between water molecules are even more important, and lead to them being close together. But in both cases, there is _some_ energy/altitude relation that leads to not all particles being at the same height.

Comment: Yes - you got the right physics in the end. But more straightforwardly, the correct starting point is noting that the atmosphere minimises its free energy, not its energy.

Answer (score 4):

In short, the air molecules stay afloat because they are bouncing off the ground and other air molecules. Here's a video visualizing that with a simple simulation based entirely on kinematic principles: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwk4mSFFop0

Answer (score 4):

What seems to have remained unmentioned in the other answers is that the air moclecules do fall to the ground: the air at higher altitudes is both more diluted and colder, which is the reflection of the trade-off between the kinetic and the potential energy of the molecules (understanding that the average kinetic energy of the molecules is temperature, and that only high energy molecules manage to climb very high).

**Update**
To expand a bit in view of the discussion that followed:
[**Barometric formula**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometric_formula) predicts that the atmospheric pressure decreases with the altitide. The formula is derived assuming that the atmosphere is in equilibrium, i.e., it can be characterized by Boltzmann temperature and constant distribution (*isothermal atmosphere*), so that the average energy of each molecule is $$\langle E\rangle=\langle\frac{mv^2}{2}\rangle+\langle mgh\rangle = \frac{3}{2} k_B T$$
(neglecting the rotational and vibrational degrees of freedom) and hence the kinetic energy decreases with height - the molecules "fall" to the ground.

In reality the atmosphere is not at constant temperature and not in thermal equilibrium: the bottom of the atmosphere is at higher temperature than its upper layers, and the warm air constantly rises, while the cold air "falls". Within hydrostatic approach this is modeled as *adiabatic atmosphere*, resulting in the equation for the temperature variation with the altitide, see [Lapse rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapse_rate). There is a good discussion of the adiabatic atmosphere in [this thread](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/4227/dry-atmospheric-temperature-profile-dry-adiabatic-vs-isothermal).

Comment: Are you sure that the fact that air higher up is colder is due to the particles losing potential energy? My intuition says that a large stack of air in equilibrium would have a higher density at the bottom but a constant temperature throughout. But I can't find a reference so I'm not sure :/

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion the air at high altitudes is colder - that's a fact. Now, you are not wrong, but it depends on what we call *temperature* - the constant in the Boltzmann distribution (average particle energy) or the average kinetic energy (which is what we perceive as temperature on Everest).

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion you are referring to the [Barometric formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometric_formula)

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion the difference is actually between the adiabatic and and the isothermal models of atmosphere - I will think about expanding my answer, to include the discussion.

Comment: I may not have been clear but I wanted to make a distinction between a temperature gradient that exists because the atmosphere is heated mainly from below and a temperature gradient that may or may not exist in an isolated air column in equilibrium.

Comment: I found this link https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/DeVoes_Thermodynamics_and_Chemistry/09%3A_Mixtures/98_Mixtures_in_Gravitational_and_Centrifugal_Fields where they state "The equation therefore tells that at equilibrium the temperature and the chemical potential of each constituent are uniform throughout the gas mixture. The equation says nothing about the pressure." for an isolated system in equilibrium.

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion You are right that the variation in temperature is the result of the atmosphere not being in equilibrium. See here, for example: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/4227/20239